# How to calculate percent change between two values in the same column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to calculate a percent change between two values in the same column in a specific form and I have no idea if what I’m trying to do is even possible.

I have a table with 3 fields

Month, Country, Value

| order_month | country | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | UK | 10 |
| 2022-02 | UK | 20 |
| 2021-01 | France | 20 |
| 2022-02 | France | 18 |
| 2021-01 | Italy | 25 |
| 2021-02 | Italy | 35 |

What I struggle to get :

| order_month | country | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | UK | 10 |
| 2022-02 | UK | 20 |
| diff | UK | 10 |
| 2021-01 | France | 20 |
| 2022-01 | France | 18 |
| diff | France | -2 |
| 2021-01 | Italy | 25 |
| 2022-02 | Italy | 35 |
| diff | Italy | 10 |

I tried many things without success. Thanks a lot if you can help me on this.

Comment: How do you know what records to subtract from eachother?   is it always just 2 records? are we always subtracting the earlier date from the older date?  order is not implied in a database....  My initial approach would be to join the two based on country and assign a row_number to each  order by date then join on country/row_number+1.  this allows us to do the subtractions on 1 record and we would have a Null order_month we could set to diff  However, Do the dates change for the two records?  too many unknowns...

Comment: Yes there is only two records that don't change and I want to do the delta between the oldest and the newest date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a49dce47bcf1448d970da0d48bf25b6f)  Granted I'm using SQL server but both support union, both support FIRST_VALUE analytic so... I think this will be ok...

Assumptions:

- Your order_month is a string or diff will be able to be used.
- the collation used supports #'s first or sort could be off.
- You're ok with country being sorted.

.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT order_month, country, value 
             FROM data 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT Distinct 'diff' order_month, country,
             FIRST_VALUE(value) over (partition by country order by order_month DESC) -
             FIRST_VALUE(value) over (partition by country order by order_month ASC) value
             FROM data) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY country, order_month
```

Giving us:

```
+-------------+---------+-------+
| order_month | country | value |
+-------------+---------+-------+
| 2021-01-01  | France  |    20 |
| 2022-02-01  | France  |    18 |
| diff        | France  |    -2 |
| 2021-01-01  | Italy   |    25 |
| 2022-02-01  | Italy   |    35 |
| diff        | Italy   |    10 |
| 2021-01-01  | UK      |    10 |
| 2022-02-01  | UK      |    20 |
| diff        | UK      |    10 |
+-------------+---------+-------+
```

What this does:

- Generate a CTE using the first_value analytic once ordered by month asc then desc.
- we then subract the older form the newer.
- we then need to group and order the data so we have a CTE we select from.
- I'm not a fan of overlading the order_month with diff
- 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LEAD/LAG window functions for this. I'd propose using this to create a new column for the difference, rather than hoping to add in a new row into the result to get the difference of the two rows above it.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  `order_month` date,
  `country` VARCHAR(6),
  `value` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO data
  (`order_month`, `country`, `value`)
VALUES
  ('2021-01-01', 'UK', '10'),
  ('2022-02-01', 'UK', '20'),
  ('2021-01-01', 'France', '20'),
  ('2022-02-01', 'France', '18'),
  ('2021-01-01', 'Italy', '25'),
  ('2022-02-01', 'Italy', '35');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select *,
VALUE - Lead(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY ORDER BY ORDER_MONTH DESC) as Month_vs_Month
from data;
```

| order_month | country | value | Month_vs_Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | France | 18 | -2 |
| 2021-01-01 | France | 20 |  |
| 2022-02-01 | Italy | 35 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | Italy | 25 |  |
| 2022-02-01 | UK | 20 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | UK | 10 |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two subqueries or CTEs that isolate the values to the months you're analyzing.

**Subquery example**

```sql
select
  country,
  value as jan_value
from {{table}}
where order_month = '2022-01'
```

Do the same for Februrary then join the tables to create a new data set with county, jan_value, and feb_value. From this dataset you can determine difference in the values.